# Tool to create wizards in C++

Tags: c++, wizard, cpropertysheet

The MFC concept (using PropertySheet / PropertyPages) to build a wizard has let me down many times and for several reasons. I googled the subject somewhat but could not turn up with any library or tool that would help me create my wizards easier.

Any recommendations would help a lot.

Comment: Do you want a wizard in windows?

Comment: "let me down" - in what ways? If you can be more specific, we can be more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at this article:

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/wizards/article.php/c5083/

[LogicNP Software](http://www.ssware.com/articles/create-wizard-user-interfaces-in-your-apps-easily-with-shellobjects.net-wizard-control.htm)